# While loop with inputs

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I'm doing a simple game for a school project. It's simply a guess the word game, and I've gotten most of it down, except for when answer is wrong or completed. Here's my code so far.

```
guess = input('Guess a letter.')



blank_answer = list('_ _ _ _ _ _')
correct_answer ='banana'
correct_answer_final = 'b a n a n a'
guess_num = 4
index_num = 0


while guess_num > 0 and "".join(blank_answer) != correct_answer_final:


    index_num = 0
    for letter in correct_answer:
        if letter == guess:
            blank_answer[index_num] = letter
        index_num += 2

    if letter != guess:
        guess_num -= 1

    print('The Word so far is ' + "".join(blank_answer)       
    guess = input('Guess a letter. (You have ' + str(guess_num) + ' guesses remaining)')

if "".join(blank_answer) == correct_answer_final:
    print('Good job ')

if guess_num == 0:
    print('sorry you ran out of guesses')
```

The main problem I'm having is after the first guess it'll say '3' guesses remaining then it'll jump to 2 after a few more guesses even if they are correct. Also it doesn't jump out of the loop right away after guessing correctly. If it is correct you have to input a correct letter once again. This was done in a graphical window, so I've changed all imported commands to default python to make it easier to understand. Any help would be great!

Comment: Your `if letter != guess` statement will only compare against the last letter from the `for letter in correct answer`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix the issue you're having but the condition for your `while` loop seems incorrect. I think what you're looking for is

```
while guess_num > 0 and "".join(blank_answer) != correct_answer_final
```

(The difference here being the `and` vs. the `or`)

This way the loop will exit if either the guesses run out OR the correct answer is guessed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I actually made an error in my question, my version has the 'and' condition and faces those problems listed. Thanks for the help though!